# Maximum number of images per question?

Tags: support

What is the maximum number of images allowed per question?  I believe it's five links per question, but unsure about images.

If there's a good way to circumvent, that would be appreciated.

Sometimes it's not possible to grab text.

(for what it's worth, pushing the limit [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1216708/).)

Comment: @Laurel, technically, while this asks "what is the image cap", it also asks "what do I do if I really need an extra image" (as this user has an enforced cap of 2). The linked question does not deal with that question, and thus, does not cover the same context as this one does.

Comment: @Gnemlock What are you talking about? Anyone over 10 rep can post [inline images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307506/6083675) and [more than 2 links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user).

Comment: @Laurel, meaning anyone under 10 can *not* post *as many* inline images. It might be a marginal exception, *but it does exist*. I honestly assumed it was higher, with the amount of legitimate questions I see where the user is unable to provide the required information due to an image cap. Again, this might be more prominant on Game Dev than other exchanges. Questions asking "what am I doing wrong" often need to include picture examples, and further images of game components, as you need to *see* what is happening (often, users that just say "this is happening" miss critical details).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a new user, the maximum is two. We get a lot of new users, over at Game Dev, performing the actions mentioned by *NVZ* after the first two images.

As per users with over 10 reputation, let's see:

[image: 1] [image: 2] [image: 3] [image: 4] [image: 5] [image: 6] [image: 7] [image: 8] [image: 9] [image: 10] [image: 11] [image: 12] [image: 13] [image: 14]

I am going to go with far more than I have time to test; but most importantly, far more than you should ever need.

---

As per needing to upload more than your allowed; once again, you should not *really* need to. An image can be compounded. If you need to upload three images, but are only restricted to two, use some simple image processing software like *paint* to make a larger image out of the two. You can label them as "figures" or "diagrams", and refer to them from your question as *"as you can see, in figure one.."*. Technically, your not actually circumnavigating the system, and your not relying on another user to fix it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I do not know for sure about the maximum limit. But a workaround for **new** users to overcome the usual limit would be to post the links to the images, with their `.com` or such URL parts broken down by spaces.

And somebody with higher rep can fix it for them. I'm not encouraging this, but just letting you know this is a possibility.

Comment: you lost me at .com.  you mean host the images somewhere?  hmm, there are all those apps for hosting images, I guess.

Comment: Keep in mind that users are probably most familiar with the built in uploader, where you ***must*** specify an absolute url. @Thufir, you can post images as links, using markup (markdown?)

Comment: ohhhh, I was uploading locally from my pc.  screenshots.  AFAIK once the images are uploaded to SO there's no distinction because they're now stored on SO itself.  AFAIK.

Comment: @Thufir, to clarify, they are stored on imgur. Stack Exchange has a deal with them, and thus, have their own "image repository" (ergo the stack overflow reference in the image links).